# How to add sort feature in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I want to get the sort order of the values of the columns and as a new column `a_order` .
For example, the order of the values is `0.5 < 2.5 < 3.6` in column `a`.

So in column `a_order`, `0.5` corresponds to `0`, `2.5` corresponds to `1`, and `3.6` corresponds to `2`.

`Input:`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.5, 3.6, 2.5]})
```

`Output:`

```
     a
0  0.5
1  3.6
2  2.5
```

`Expected:`

```
     a  a_order
0  0.5        0
1  3.6        2
2  2.5        1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html), subtract `1` and convert to integers:

```
df['a_order'] = df['a'].rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)
print (df)
     a  a_order
0  0.5        0
1  3.6        2
2  2.5        1
```

Comment: Please revert the previous edit. It actually gives a good idea if duplicates exist and the user will get to know what to use.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - I remove it because it return bad values, I was wrong with duplicated values. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53115324/revisions)

Comment: We have a `method = 'first'` which will take care of duplicates in rank. Check it once.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - There was problem exected output, because `argsort` return indices by sorted values, so not possible use here :(

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I meant to check this `df['a'].rank(method='first').sub(1).astype(int)` with duplicated data. As, parameter `method='first'` taking care of it.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Yes, I agree with you. I say about `argsort` and you about `method='first'`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
df['a_order']=df.sort_values('a').index.tolist()
```

Assign `'a_order'` as the index of the sorted data-frame by the `'a'` column

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your solution is not I expected. I just compare all the values in a column, and take the order as a new column. For example, if there are four values `0.5, 3.6, 2.5, 0.0` in column `a`, I expect `1, 3, 2, 0` in column `a_order`.

Comment: @rosefun How come?, can you please try it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.ndarray.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html):

```
df['a_order'] = df['a'].values.argsort()

print(df)

     a  a_order
0  0.5        0
1  3.6        2
2  2.5        1
```